# Why Windows 10 Settings appllication show in French even after changing everything to English?

Tags: windows, windows-10, language, windows-10-v1909

I'm trying to change my Windows to English but I can't get it to work. Here are the steps that I did so far.

1) Installed the English Language Pack and define it as default:

[image: English Language Pack]

2) Copy settings:

[image: Copy Settings]

3) Restart computer!

Even with all that and deleting the French Language Pack, my Settings app and other parts of Windows still display in French.

[image: Settings Application]

I'm using version 1909.

[image: Windows Version]

Comment: You should check the two boxes in the "Welcome screen and new user..." window too. After that, it's a matter of restarting your PC without Fast Startup, otherwise, some changes in UI don't work. And don't blame the French...! :-) EDIT: I hadn't noticed that your Windows is an Enterprise version. There might be a GPO or two that prevent you from switching from one language to the other completely. Check them out first. See here: https://dennisspan.com/configuring-regional-settings-and-windows-locales-with-group-policy/

Comment: ... And here: https://www.microsoftpartnercommunity.com/t5/Products-Discussions/change-region-and-language-settings-using-group-policy/td-p/5625

Comment: Did you download the Language Pack? *"Ajouter une langue d'affichage"* in blue in top picture.